# Openstack VPNaaS tunnel sharing option

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I am currently configuring a VPN using the VPNaaS of neutron. We are setting an IPSec tunnel with an external partner. The communication is established, but he ask me what type of tunnel sharing we are using. Here are the options he gave me:

- One VPN tunnel per each pair of hosts
- One VPN tunnel per subnet pair
- One VPN tunnel per Gateway pair

I do not know how Openstack will configure this options, and I do not know were to look at this.

Does anyone know where to look at?